# Splitting Integers

Tags: java

A small portion of a program I am trying to solve involves splitting a number into different combinations of consecutive digits.

For example the integer 12345 can be split into 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 23, 34, 45, 123, 234, 345, 1234, 2345.

As a beginner programmer myself, I know how to split an integer by module division and for loops, but I have no idea how to start separating digits by groups like this in an algorithm. Any hints are appreciated. I am not asking someone to code it for me.

Comment: I can think of a lot of ways to do this very easily. Maybe you should take the time to think about it and you'll see, the solution will pop up. :)

Comment: For instance try some operation on string value of this integer and creating substrings.

Comment: This is easier if you convert the integer to a String. Although 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 are not combinations of consecutive digits.

Comment: [Here you go](http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2014/02/algorithm-for-combinations-of-string-java-code-with-example.html)

Answer (score 1):

check this code maybe help

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 12345;
        String str ,numStr = Integer.toString(num);

        for (int j=1 ; j<numStr.length() ;j++) {
            for (int i=0 ;i<numStr.length() ; i++){
                if (i+j <=numStr.length()) {
                    str = numStr.substring(i, i+j);
                    System.out.println(str+",");
                }

            }
            System.out.println("-------------");
        }
    }

}
```